# Set default data path for every project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

### Eclipse project/folder structure:

```
 src
    java files
  bin
    class files
  resources
    data files
```

Is there a way to set the default data path to project/resources in Eclipse, such as setting a classpath variable as MY_DATA_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a library project and keep the content of the lib or any other project folder you want in this library project.

Reference this project in your other project. This will allow you to have a common path across all project for any project folder like lib, SRC, asset

Any content with same name and project folder in referencing project will over write that particular content of library project.

Comment: Sorry, don't quite understand. Do you mean to create a library project such as libPro, I will set the data path to libPro/resources. Then when I have a new project newPro to reference this libPro, Eclipse will automatically include and search newPro/resources for data?